# type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'int'

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new on flutter. I just wanted to store best score value. I tried to use Shared Preferences but i got an error.

```
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

int best;

setBest(int n) async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  prefs.setInt('best', n);
}

getBest() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  int intValue = prefs.getInt('best');
  if (intValue == null) {
    return 0;
  }
  return intValue;
}
```

I call this dart file an another dart file
'import .... as x'
This pages shows to the user their current score and best

```
int best = x.getBest();

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if (score > best) {
      best = score;
      x.setBest(score);
    }
  }
```

error message

```
Exception caught by widgets library    
The following _TypeError was thrown building Builder:
type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'int'
The relevant error-causing widget was MaterialApp lib\main.dart:9
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0 new _QuizResultState  package:quiz_game/pages/quiz_result.dart:16
#1 QuizResult.createState package:quiz_game/pages/quiz_result.dart:12
#2 new StatefulElement package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4591
#3 StatefulWidget.createElement package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:894
Normal element mounting (115 frames)
```

Comment: Include the _full_ error message in question bodies, and indicate the representative line(s).

Answer (score 1):

When you put `async` in a method, this method will return a `Future<dynamic>` object, so in second block of code you try to put a future inside a int:

```dart
int best = x.getBest();
```

To solve this I suggest:

```dart
Future<int> best = x.getBest();

@override
void initState() async {
  super.initState();
  if (score > await best) {
    best = Future.sync(score);
    x.setBest(score);
  }
}
```

Comment: There is a blue line under await. 'await' applied to 'int', which is not a 'Future'.  And still i'm getting same error.

Comment: So like @user2864740 said, we need a full error stack to help you

Comment: This is my full error :). When my second code (initState ..) work i get the error on my phone with red background and yellow text color.

Comment: best = Future.sync(score); red line under the score. The argument type 'int' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'FutureOr<int> Function()' Is there any way to store best score? :)